# Python - testear función que devuelve print

Tags: python, test

Quiero hacer el testeo de una función que recoge un dato de usuario (input) y devuelve una frase.
La función he comprobado que funciona correctamente.

La función es la siguiente:

```
approval_polls_entry = ' /home/.../Data/...csv'

def url_pdf_counter(approval_polls_entry):

    # call function
    covid_approval_polls = pd.read_csv(approval_polls_entry)

    # repeated times - url w/ pdf format
    urls = covid_approval_polls.url
    # regex code
    urls_regexp = r"^https?://.*\.pdf$"
    url_count = [
        approval
        for approval in urls
        if re.match(urls_regexp, approval) is not None
    ]
    len_url_count = len(url_count)
    print("  The pattern url_pdf appears {} times".format(len_url_count))
```

El código para testear se me ocurre sólo este, sabiendo cuál es el resultado final:

```
def test_url_pdf_counter(self):
        print('Starting test_url_pdf_counter')
        self.assertEqual(url_pdf_counter approval_polls_entry),"  The pattern url_pdf appears 112 times")
```

Al ejecutar me devuelve un error

```
AssertionError: None != '  The pattern url_pdf appears 112 times'
```

No sé cómo verificar que el texto aparece y que la cuenta se realiza correctamente ya que la función no devuelve el número y no creo que deba hacerlo únicamente para poder hacer el testeo.

Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, más o menos estoy entendiendo tu pregunta. Necesito algo más de contexto. Sobre la pregunta (1), con _inputs_, te refieres a los parámetros de la función? Qué es `keyword`, dentro de `url_pdf_counter()`? Qué función cumple? Porque como en la definición del método no haces referencia a ella, no logro entender para qué la usarías al pasarla en la llamada a la función.

Comment: @carlosabcs, he visto que estaba haciendo la llamada de forma incorrecta según lo que indicaba en la duda, pero actualizando a lo que me ocurre ahora, tengo el error de salida que acabo de editar. Perdona.

Comment: que hace la funcion `url_pdf_counter()`, solo te devuelve el numero de veces que aparece la palabra dependiendo del archivo? o hace algo mas?

Comment: @Christian, correcto. De un dataset, las cuenta

Comment: entonces quieres que el testeo consista en pasarle distintos archivos, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal sería que la función no imprimiera, sino que devolviera un string y afuera (en el código cliente) hicieras la impresión. De esa manera, puedes probar fácilmente con la aserción que has puesto.

Pero para responder tal cual tu pregunta, la manera de probar que en consola se está imprimiendo lo que quieres es a través de capturar el valor de `sys.stdout`, que es quien contiene las salidas por terminal de nuestro código. Una forma de capturarlo es valiéndote de `StringIO`

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
import io
import sys
from unittest import TestCase

# [ Importación de tu código acá]


class TestPrinting(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.captured_output = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = self.captured_output

    def test_url_pdf_counter(self):
        expected_output = "  The pattern url_pdf appears 112 times\n"
        url_pdf_counter(approval_polls_entry)    # <-- no dejas claro cuál es el valor de approval_polls_entry, pero tú sabrás cuál es el valor que produce la salida que esperas
        self.assertEqual(
            expected_output,
            self.captured_output.getvalue(),
            msg=f'The output was expected to be {expected_output}'
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Nota: Atento a colocar el carácter de nueva línea (`\n`) después de tu salida esperada, ya que la función `print()` lo añade por defecto.

Comment: muchas gracias. Ejecutando el código me da el mensaje ```AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'getvalue'``` \n Sobre tu comentario en el código, ```approval_polls_entry``` es un dataset en el que en una columna están los URLs que luego se cuentan

Comment: siguiendo tu primer consejo, he modificado la función y desde el MAIN indico el código para pasar por pantalla. Gracias!

Comment: Sí, pero igual no sé por qué te aparece ese error Esa "receta" es la que siempre uso cuando quiero comprobar salida por pantalla y pues siempre funciona. Asegúrate de estar siguiéndola a cabalidad, porque pareciera que en lugar de asignar `StringIO`, estuvieras asignando `TestIOWrapper` a `self.captured_output`.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, sobre el error, te faltan unos paréntesis para indicar que `approval_polls_entry` es el parámetro que estás enviando:

```py
self.assertEqual(url_pdf_counter(approval_polls_entry)),"  The pattern url_pdf appears 112 times")
```

Puede ser que por eso te retorne `None`.

Estoy notando que usas `approval_polls_entry` como variable al inicio del código y luego de nuevo como nombre del argumento que recibe `url_pdf_counter`, pero creo que todo bien con eso.

Lo segundo:

> No sé cómo verificar que el texto aparece y que la cuenta se realiza
> correctamente ya que la función no devuelve el número y no creo que
> deba hacerlo únicamente para poder hacer el testeo.

Yo haría un refactor, dos funciones, una que retorne el conteo (lo que estás haciendo actualmente) y otra que agregue el mensaje al conteo. Usaría la primera para las pruebas y la segunda para el resto de casos. Así:

```py
def url_pdf_counter(approval_polls_entry):

    # call function
    covid_approval_polls = pd.read_csv(approval_polls_entry)

    # repeated times - url w/ pdf format
    urls = covid_approval_polls.url
    # regex code
    urls_regexp = r"^https?://.*\.pdf$"
    url_count = [
        approval
        for approval in urls
        if re.match(urls_regexp, approval) is not None
    ]
    return len(url_count)


def print_url_pdf_count(approval_polls_entry):
    print("  The pattern url_pdf appears {} times".format(url_pdf_counter(approval_polls_entry))

print_url_pdf_count(approval_polls_entry)
# Retornaría:
# "  The pattern url_pdf appears un_valor times"
```

Comment: pero estoy tratando de utilizar ```unittest```